# In what scenarios are onPause and onResume() inconsistent?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, onresume, onpause

I know that in Android `onPause()` and `onResume()` can be inconsistent sometimes.

(For example, if the user is pulling down the notifications thing from the top of the screen `onPause()` will not be called even though the activity is partially obscured.)

So I was wondering, in what scenarios are onPause/onResume not called even if the screen becomes partially obscured.

Comment: Partial obscurity is fine. When a foreign item takes focus of the whole screen or something similar then the correct lifecycle methods get called.

Comment: @TheSunny I suppose then the question is in what instances is the screen partially obscured. So far I can only think of 2 instance (when a call is received or the user receives notifications).

Comment: Correct. When another activity/fragment/view overlays your views then your app goes into pause mode.